# Draw something from a relative coordinate, then return to the coordinate and draw something else

Tags: tikz-pgf

I often want to draw several things relative to one specific coordinate which was reached while drawing a path with TikZ. Is there a way to open up a "scope" from the current position, draw something and then return to the position for another scope?

Consider this example, where I want to go from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` and from there to both

- `(2,1)` using `++(1,0)`
- and `(2,2)` using `++(1,1)`

without having to manually reset the position to `(1,1)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)
-- ++(1,1)
-- ++(1,1)
(1,1) -- ++(1,0); % <- avoid hard coded reset
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the purpose of symbolic coordinates.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)
-- ++(1,1) coordinate(aux)
-- ++(1,1)
(aux) -- ++(1,0); % <- avoid hard coded reset
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick (and works repetitively with the same name so I don't need to think of messy coordinate names just for creating a local scope)